# Выбрать общую сумму оплаты за продукты за год

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, mariadb

Использую MariaDB 10.5.12.
В БД есть поля:

```
price      decimal(5,2)
currency   enum('', 'usd', 'eur')
date       varchar(255)
```

В поле date хранится дата в свободном стиле, вроде 27 jan или 15*
Если в поле date есть * - это означает помесячную оплату, иначе раз в год.

Нужно выбрать общую сумму за все товары за определённый месяц, делаю это запросом:

```
SELECT SUM(`price`) FROM `subscriptions` WHERE (`date` LIKE '%".$this->_dbconn->real_escape_string(strtolower($month))."%' OR `date` LIKE '%*%') AND `currency` = 'usd'
```

А вот как выбрать сумму за все товары за весь год? Т.е. нужно выбрать SUM(`price`) всех столбцов, но там где в поле date есть * нужно поле price умножить на 12. Помогите написать SQL запрос.

Comment: так как дата записываеться в 27 jan - то задача не имеет решения, нет признака года. возможно если бы был АЙ дишник автоинкремент, то  эмперическим способом можно было бы узнать 1 оплату за 1 января 2021 года    условно  ID = 1015, тогда    sum(price)   WHERE ID >= 1015

Comment: @VitSaha подозреваю, что таблица содержит сведения только за текущий год.

Comment: `sum(case when date like '%*%' then price*12 else price end)`

Comment: если только за текущий то селект сумм   без условий  как легкая рекомендация date       varchar(255)   =>> хотя бы date_insert       varchar(255)   /// поуникальнее чем стандартые функции ( в данном случае поле data    ==== data ( SQL

Answer (score 0):

Я не совсем понимаю как именно выглядит твоя таблица, но можно просто запросить сумму всех строк определённого поля `SELECT SUM('price') FROM subscriptions WHERE date>=1`
Запрос начального уровня получается и это единственное, что я смог написать исходя из твоего описания.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).